# Why Getting reCAPTCHA browser-error on iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am using google reCAPTCHA v3 and getting below response on iPhone.

```
{"success":false,"error-codes":["browser-error"]}
```

What could be the cause of this error?

Thanks in Advance.